# Matplotlib plot from Python script not showing up in output when run in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Trying to run a Python script from the directory that my Jupyter notebook is in. The script executes as expected, but the plot does not show up in the output in my Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried adding code like plt.show() to the test script, but it doesn't show the graph in the Jupyter output. I have also tried adding %matplotlib inline to the Jupyter cell, but that doesn't help either.

In Jupyter Notebook cell:

```py
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
!python test_plot.py
```

In the test_plot.py Python script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
plt.show()
```

Expected Results:
When I run the code straight in the notebook,

```py
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
```

it produces a piecewise function. (Can't post image due to low reputation). However, this is not the actual result.

Actual results printed in Jupyter Cell:
Figure(640x480)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using:

```py
%run 'test_plot.py'
```

as opposed to

```py
!python test_plot.py
```

You should be able to run the cell correctly with the desired chart being plotted

Comment: This fixed it! I realized this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163470/how-to-execute-a-py-file-from-a-ipynb-file-on-the-jupyter-notebook) only after I posted the original question, but this result did not come up in any of my original search queries, so I'd argue that this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Hi @BDavis, it is not yet clear the actual differences between running `!ipython` and `%run` in Jupyter Notebooks and perhaps that could be a question on its own, to try to understand what happens under the hood for both commands.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for weeks and it was driving me insane.