# How to run python script on gpu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

Within my jupyter notebook, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True`. But when I run a python script, that same line of code in the python script returns `False`. This suggests to me that when I run a python script in my notebook, it does not default to using cuda. Any workaround?

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question, not as a link to an image.

Comment: To me it seems that the python you refer to does not have the correct linking to cuda, so you would need to fix that.

Comment: You may want to check which python is by default on your system. Try `!python --version` to check which version you are using from command line.

Comment: And to know which version you are running from Jupiter try `import sys` and then `sys.version`.

Comment: @Marc what do you mean by "correct linking"? How would i link it?

Comment: @CedricZoppolo I got Python 3.6.8

Comment: It would be easier I think to go with @CedricZoppolo his strategy and refer to the same python as the one your jupyter is using since it is already working there

Comment: @Marc and how would i refer to the python that my jupyter is using

Comment: On my system that's easy as my jupyter notebook uses python 3.7.6 and to use that one I can use the command "python3" instead of the standard "python" but it depends on your system. What OS are you on?

Comment: @Marc I'm using a cloud computing service called paperspace. I've tried python3. Same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following:

```
%run -i test_background-matting_image.py -m real-hand-held -i sample_data/input/ -o sample_data/output/ -tb sample_data/background/0001.png
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163470/how-to-execute-a-py-file-from-a-ipynb-file-on-the-jupyter-notebook): `%run -i` runs the file in IPython’s namespace instead of an empty one i.e the "same python" as my jupyter notebook.