# Call Python file with main method inside Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem. I want to call inside my Jupyter Notebook a Python File. I looked at [How to execute a * .PY file from a * .IPYNB file on the Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163470/how-to-execute-a-py-file-from-a-ipynb-file-on-the-jupyter-notebook) but unfortunately `%run -i 'file.py'` and `!python file.py` does not work, because my file is not in the same folder as the Jupyter Notebook file.

So how could I call a Python file from a different folder?
Jupyter Notebook

```py
from pathlib import *
# I am using pathlib, because of the whitespace in OneDrive
p = Path('C://Users//user//OneDrive - user//folder//file.py')
# %run -i ''C://Users//user//OneDrive - user//folder//file.py'
!python p
[OUT] python: can't open file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\p': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

file.py

```py
def main():
    print("Hello")
    return "test"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chdir()` changes the current working directory to the given path.

This should do your work:

```
import os
filepath = r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive - user\folder' 
os.chdir(filepath)
%run file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is in a sub-folder `./playground/test folder`, then you could do this:

```py
file_name = ".\\playground\\test folder\\hello_world.py"

%run "$file_name"
```

The trick is to use quotation marks around the file name (if path  contains spaces) when using [`%run`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).

The same applies if you use `!python`:

```py
file_name = ".\\playground\\test folder\\hello_world.py"

!python "$file_name"
```